# e.labels.map is not a function when creating a chart with chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to create a Pie chart on chart.js. It always comes with a error message of e.labels.map is not a function when I'm trying to put an array of labels inside chart js.
Is it my chart js code structure is wrong or do i need to change my data?
Thanks

```js
function drawactivitygraph() {
    var exmin = null;
    var activities = null;
    var colorarray = null;

    var noactivities = document.getElementById('exnum').value;

    exmin = [];
    activities = []
    colorarray = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= noactivities; i++) {
        var minutes = document.getElementById(`minutes${i}`).value;
        var activity = document.getElementById(`exercisetype${i}`).value;
        exmin.push(minutes);
        activities.push(activity);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < noactivities; i++) {
        var randomcolor =getRandomColor();
        colorarray.push(randomcolor);
    }
    var ctx = document.getElementById('actgraph').getContext('2d');
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        // The type of chart we want to create
        type: 'pie',

        // The data for our dataset
        data: {
            labels: activity,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Activities',
                backgroundColor: colorarray,
                //borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                data: minutes
            }]
        },

        // Configuration options go here
        options: {}
    });

}
```

Here is the error message

[image]

Comment: Also here is additional errors.

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean `labels: activities` rather than `labels: activity` in your Chart constructor, since `activity` does not exist at that point..